# Track User Information that Uninstall Android/iOS App

Tags: android, ios, analytics

So, I want to track who's uninstalling my app. I know there's bunch of uninstall tracker, but as far as I know there's just only for tracking how many uninstall number and which activity/page that user access before uninstalling the app. I haven't found any uninstall tracker that track user information yet. Is there any? Or is it even possible to track such information?

Thank you.

Edit : I'm not only need to track uninstall but also track who's uninstall my app by name, email, and/or phone number. Note that my app has login activity so I already have user information stored in database. My app also using OneSignal for push notification so we have device id to track the device, if that's helpful.

Comment: what information you call *user information*

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko such as email and name, and _possibly_ phone number.

Comment: You can't do anything during app uninstall. WHat you can do is track when the app was last used

Comment: I see, thank you. I saw a trick using FCM though. Might try that soon.